# Why create a pointer in C when you can just point directly to the variable as a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, idioms

I'm learning C and came across an example that kind of seems like it creates an unecessary step, but again I'm new to this.

He created a variable, and then a dedicated pointer to point to that variable. It is my understanding that you could simple put an * in front of the variable and that will serve as a pointer to it...so why use another line of code to create a pointer? Specifically I'm talking about why he created the pointer "*p" just to refer to "x" vs just saying *x to point to it. Below is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;            /* A normal integer*/
    int *p;           /* A pointer to an integer ("*p" is an integer, so p
                   must be a pointer to an integer) */
    p = &x;           /* Read it, "assign the address of x to p" */
    scanf( "%d", &x );          /* Put a value in x, we could also use p here */
    printf( "%d\n", *p ); /* Note the use of the * to get the value */
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Refer this for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: Because the pointer needs to **point** somwhere...

Comment: Yes, in `printf` you could use directly `x` instead of `*p` or `*&x`  .  I think this code is just an example to show how pointer can be used.

Comment: @Christophe as well as in `scanf` the OP could do `scanf("%d", p);`.

Comment: while this code might be a nice beginning exercise in using pointers.  in this case the pointer is actually unneeded..   There are lots of scenarios where a pointer is actually needed, so this is a good time to learn/understand them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's right you don't need the extra pointer object.

You program is equivalent in behavior to:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
printf("%d\n", x);
getchar();
```

The use of the extra pointer in the example is probably for didactic reasons: to explain how to declare and use pointers.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I figured...it didn't seem mandatory and to me kind of makes it feel like the code jumps everywhere so it's something I wanted to avoid in practice if possible.